# Change IO pub data rate limit on Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, google-colaboratory

**How do I change the IO pub data rate limit on Google Colab? I want to upload a file from my drive but I keep getting this error message:**

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a minimal repro notebook? Uploading a file shouldn't trigger that limit.